# What are the Devops-related conferences happening around the world?

Tags: conferences

This is a similar question like the [Statistics Conferences question at CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/statistics-conferences)

What are the Devops or Devops-related conferences happening around the world?

Rules:

- Include a link to the conference
- Please include links for the talks, e.g. youtube, the conference site or some other video streaming site

Comment: I think you should try to rephrase "most", "significant" and "annual" (eg to avoid it is closed as an opinion based question). Eg: just omit all 3 words? Be aware: there are such conferences that are not exactly "annual" (eg: every 18 months ...) Also, try to describe the "relationship" (as per your "related". PS: Devops or DevOps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a list question and those are not allowed on SE sites. Some sites do allow it, but only on meta or only as community-wiki question.

Comment: @THelper I have already flagged it for the mods to make it a community-wiki :) So, I request you to re-consider your vote!

Comment: Ok, that helps. But I'm wondering how long this list of conferences is going to be. If I google on "devops conference" I get 50.000+ hits. I am in favor of community-wiki list questions as long as the lists are relatively short. For questions with long lists and/or lists that change rapidly I'm against.

Comment: I agree with @THelper. I don't think this question is suitable for a Q&A format. There's just too many answers, too much location specific and events could rapidly change (no use for future readers unless well maintained).

Comment: More information about why I think we should not allow questions like this in this meta question: [What is our take on list-style community-wiki questions?](http://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/101/460)

Comment: Probably not an answer, but just in case: https://www.meetup.com/topics/devops/

Comment: Also http://devopsconferences.org/

Answer (score 2):

[Velocity Conference](https://conferences.oreilly.com/velocity) is one of the most popular Devops conferences, and also is an O'Reilly conference.

From it's website:

> At Velocity, systems, site reliability, and systems engineers, systems
>   architects, and application developers learn to build and manage fast,
>   resilient, and highly available websites and apps.

The videos of the conference are present on [O'Reilly's youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/OreillyMedia/search?query=velocity).

Answer (score 1):

This question reminded me about this quote about the [Etymology of DevOps, From Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps):

> At the Agile 2008 conference, Andrew Clay Shafer and Patrick Debois discussed "[Agile Infrastructure](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2008/10/09/agile-2008-toronto-agile-infrastructure-and-operations-presentation/)". The term DevOps was popularized through a series of ["devopsdays" starting in 2009 in Belgium](http://www.devopsdays.org/events/2009-ghent/). Since then, there have been devopsdays conferences, held in [many countries, worldwide](http://www.devopsdays.org/).

So at the risk it may not 100% fit the rules in your question, I thought I'd post what, IMO, is "the reference" to get an up-to-date answer if you ever wonder something like

> **What's up in DevOps-land?**

In such case, you probably can find the answer to your question at http://www.devopsdays.org/ .

At this very moment, it shows links to these locations:

> Beijing - Vancouver - Denver - Atlanta - Tokyo - Seattle - Zürich - Austin - Stockholm - Salt Lake City - Toronto - Amsterdam - Washington, DC - Minneapolis - Portland - Dallas - Raleigh - Chicago - Detroit - Istanbul - Paris - Hartford - Philadelphia - Oslo - Cape Town

PS: From the above quote, it should also be clear what the relationship is with DevOps and Chocolats, Beer, Fries and ... Drupal.